# How to add function decorator to class method that accepts this class as one of decorator call arguments

Tags: python

When I try code like this:

```
def type_check(types):
  def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(self, v):
      if not type(v) in types:
        raise TypeError('Value is of type {} but allowed type(s): {}.'.format(type(v), types))
      return f(self, v)
    return wrapper
  return decorator

class MyList:
  @type_check(types=[list, MyList])
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.data = value[:]
  # ... next are operator overloading and other unrelated to question code ...
```

I getting following traceback output:

> ```
> MyList
> @type_check(types=[list, MyList]) NameError: name 'MyList' is not defined
> ```

I bypassed this by subclassing MyList from MyListAnchor and checking types with isinstance() instead of strict type equality:

```
def type_check(types):
  def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(self, v):
      if not any(filter(lambda t: isinstance(v, t), types)):
        raise TypeError('Value is of type {} but must be an instance(s) of: {}.'.format(type(v), types))
      return f(self, v)
    return wrapper
  return decorator

class MyListAnchor:
  pass

class MyList(MyListAnchor):
  @type_check(types=[list, MyListAnchor])
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.data = value[:]
  # ... next are operator overloading and other unrelated to question code ...
```

Is this the best solution? How to add function decorator to class method that accepts this class as one of decorator call arguments?

UPDATE: I generalized decorator and workarounded initial problem with class decorator:

```
"""
Type constrains format:
  'method_name': (pargs, kargs)
where pargs - list of constrains for positional only arguments, like this
  [[], [str, int], [Self]]
where empty list designate an absense of constrains and Self stands for class decorator
was added to.
Similarly kargs have format:
  {'aname_0': [], 'aname_1': [str, int], 'aname_2': [Self]}
WARNING:
  1) Positional only arguments in class methods constraned by this decorator must not
be passed by name (in keyworld-only args manner).
    Having "def foo(x, y, z): ..." call it like "foo(1, 2, 3)" but not "foo(1, 2, z=3)"
    or place constrains for "z" in either pargs or kargs. In either way you have to sacrifice
    some flexibility in way you pass args in method and do not mixing args passing styles (choose
    "foo(1, 2, 3)" or "foo(1, 2, z=3)") 
  2) When you call method with extra arguments (*pargs and **kwargs), extra arguments in *pargs and **kargs constrained
      by pargs[-1] or kargs[None].
"""
class Self: pass

def type_check(ptypes, ktypes):
  def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*pargs, **kargs):
      i = 0
      while i < len(pargs):
        arg = pargs[i]
        types = ptypes[i] if i < len(ptypes) else ptypes[-1]
        if types and not type(arg) in types:
          raise TypeError('Value is of type {} but allowed type(s): {}.'.format(type(arg), types))
        i += 1
      for k, v in kargs.items():
        types = ktypes[k] if k in ktypes else ktypes[None]
        if not type(v) in types:
          raise TypeError('Value is of type {} but allowed type(s): {}.'.format(type(v), types))
      return f(*pargs, **kargs)
    return wrapper
  return decorator

def methods_constrained(meth_cons: dict):
  def decorator(c):
    for meth, (ptypes, ktypes) in meth_cons.items():
      for i in range(len(ptypes)):
        ptypes[i] = [c if t == Self else t for t in ptypes[i]]
      for k in ktypes:
        ktypes[k] = [c if t == Self else t for t in ktypes[k]]
      exec('c.{} = type_check(ptypes, ktypes)(c.__dict__[meth])'.format(meth))
    return c
  return decorator
```

And usage example:

```
import strict_types as st

@st.methods_constrained({
  '__init__': ([[], [list, st.Self]], {}),
  'foo': ([[], [dict, st.Self], [int, float], [str]], {'w': [st.Self], 'z': [float], 'qwerty': [bool], None: [bool]}),
})
class MyList:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.data = value[:]
  def foo(self, x, y=1, *pargs, w, z=2, **kargs):
    print(self, x, y, pargs, w, z, kargs)
# ... next are operator overloading and other unrelated to question code ...

i = MyList([1, 2, 3])
i.foo({'key1': 'value'}, 3.14, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', w=i, z=0.1, qwerty=True, b0=False, b1=False, b2=True)
```

May be later I'll add auto retrieving information about constrains from args annotations (but in this case only one type will be allowed). Also I did not thinking about what is better - strict type equality or isinstance() - or may be both with choosing equality mode via decorator's args (with default to strict).

P.S.: This question is not a try to reinvent the wheel in python static typing but just a practice on python decorators topic.

Comment: You should probably use Python's type annotations and http://mypy-lang.org for type-checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decorate `__init__` **after** the class is defined:

```
class MyList:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.data = value[:]

MyList.__init__ = type_check(types=[list, MyList])(MyList.__init__)
```

Comment: I think this is what metaclasses intended for - tuning class after creation. But I only in the beginning my python way and metaclasses is still some magic for me. Thank you!

Comment: Metaclasses don't tune classes after creation: they *create* classes. *Decorators* modify classes after they are created.

Comment: @chepner yeah you right, i've updated look at my masterpiece :)